# login option on website

Tags: php, html

i made a website,  i have a webpage http://www.itstanmoy.in/download.html/ on that website. i want when i guest try to access that page he/she have to login via facebook, how can i do this?

Comment: Start here: http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Facebook connect](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=730)

Answer (score 1):

You could have just Googled this, but check out
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: i swear a majority of questions on here could be answered with google :/

Comment: Guess that's one of the few downsides of the reputation system, people are so motivated to gain reputation points they don't mind performing Google searches for each other. Right?

Answer (score 1):

[developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) will tell you what you need to know.

Basically, you'll need to check if they're authenticated with facebook on your webpage. If they're not, ask them to authorize using facebook.

It's a pretty simple script once you get the ins and outs sorted!

Comment: if i want to add a sign up and sign in option for that page what i have to do?

Comment: It's all in the documentation. As Weasley said - you need to look into Facebook Connect.